# Splitting a KML file by year / location

Tags: windows, data, gps, kml

I have a large KML file containing enough data to cause most programs including Google Earth to have problems.

I would like to divide it by year.

However, if it could detect when I left my home city, and returned via airport and split that data out that would be even better.  The data is all there in the KML file.

I would like this to be for Windows, but I have linux computers available if necessary. As for the price, it depends what the software does if its a one trick pony less than $100. If all it did was divide by year I would expect a much lower cost, if it meets the extended goals I will be more forgiving.

If your going to suggest Qgis or similar, I will need exact step by step instruction because I have tried it.  All I got was blank spaces.  I selected a US data once, but nothing was displayed on the screen as a result.

There was a similar question mar 20 2015 however they failed to provide enough information for a novice to follow.

Comment: You could try this https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/   I don't know what data do you want to convert from kml to what data ?

Comment: @PROBERT  I want to split the data I said nothing about a format change.  If I want to do a format change GPSBabel will convert it to any of 2 dozen plus formats.